# Error viewing revisions list of an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list

Page that triggers this:

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/posts/9323/revisions

Another moderator and I get an error when viewing the above link. It seems to only happen on [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9320/can-the-bitcoin-network-be-used-for-cracking/9323#9323). As far as I know, there's nothing else odd about this answer or its parent question.

Comment: The [timeline](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/posts/9323/timeline) is working, I only see the edits made by you and the other moderator, do you see something weird, as a moderator? (e.g. reduction of a revision?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Timeline works for me too.

Comment: Yes I know, Oded solved this already.. Why did you put 3383383619236481 as list item  number? I'd say it is something very odd about this answer. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't actually remember doing it. Converting the numbers to hex, none of them are special or anything; they look like keyboard pounding.

Comment: But... you did it. Doesn't really matter, it would have happened at some point anyway, lol. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard To clarify, the timeline already worked, before Oded fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the original revision of the post had a list that started like this:

```
3383383619236481. Blocks are exactly...
```

(original revision can be seen [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/posts/9323/edit/6cc18506-4fae-46f7-892d-4d3d34f9cbe4), if you have enough rep on bitcoin.se)

That right. A super long number. I guess this was the OPs idea of a joke (the other values for the ordered list were just as long).

Fast forward a bit - we added the ability to choose what number to start an ordered list with. To support that (and to be able to increment the values for the following items), we need to parse that number out - and in this case, well... this value doesn't fit into an Int32. So trying to convert the markdown to HTML fails. In fact, trying to *post* something with such a list would currently fail.

Until now - I've added a check to see if the value will fit into an Int32. If it will not, the list will start without a specific number. Side effect is that trying to submit lists that start with such numbers will work, though they will render starting with 1. With you in the next build.

Comment: Int32.TryParse for the rescue?

Comment: Will it affect that buggy revision, or would we still get an error when trying to view it? (after next build.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yeah, `TryParse`... And it _should_ be fixed after the next build.

Comment: Int32?!? This is an outrage. How am I supposed to start a list with Graham's Number?

Comment: I will be working on block-chain support for list items - no estimate of when that will be done, @NickODell

Comment: @Oded what about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279194/152859)? Look really odd, you consider this a bug, or better let it be, and hope that people won't abuse it? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yeah, I kinda expected that to happen... TBH - better than crashing server side, and easy to edit to fix.